# Magento 2 how to get order id on admin order invoice save?

Tags: magento2, orders, overrides, plugin, sales-invoice

How to get order id in invoice using plugin ?

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save">
        <plugin name="admin_plugin_order_invoice_save_after" type="Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Save.php**

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory;

class Save 
{
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save $subject,$result)
    {
        echo "order id ---".$result->getEntityId();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result->getData());
        
        
        die;
    }
}
```

Unable to get anything.
Using this code unable to get order it or invoice id.
Anyone know how to get order id,update order or get invoice id ?

Comment: Do you want invoice id or Order id?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya order id

Comment: I post answer, please check if that help you.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i used to get order id using registry invoice.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the Save.php as below and you will get the order id

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory;

class Save 
{

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save $subject, $result)
    {
        $invoice = $this->registry->register('current_invoice');
        $orderId = $invoice->getOrderId();
        $invoiceId = $invoice->getId();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i also use same using registry but it is safe using invoice registry ?

Comment: Yes it is safe. You are just using the register data only. You are not modify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Order Id in this way.

```
class Save 
{
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save $subject,$result)
    {
        $orderId = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        echo $orderId;
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can Try this
  Venddor/Module/etc/event.xml 

<event name="sales_order_save_after">
  <observer name="reward_ggn" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ClassName"/>
</event>
```

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class ClassName implements ObserverInterface 
{

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
 {      
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            if($order->getState() == 'complete') {
               
            $order->getOrderId();
            }       
 }
 }
```

Comment: i want to use with plugin not event